# Rails respond_to throw ActionController::UnknownFormat

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

So, I'm trying to respond to an action with a js file.

```
  def my_schedule
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

In my view, I have 'my_schedule.js.erb' but it's not even executed, rails broke in the controller and throw me an error : ActionController::UnknownFormat, where I have the respond_to.

I tried to add

```
respond_to :js, :json, :html
```

at the beginning of my controller out of the actions but still not working.
Need help to debug this and understand how respond_to really works.

Comment: Do you have `remote: true` in your view?

Comment: No, my html.erb file contains only html without any form, and my js.erb either. I haven't anything in it yet. I just wanted to test for now if I can access to it. I'd like to respond with my js.erb in order to send an ajax request to my controller to create a new model

Answer (score 0):

`format.js` will only respond to an xhr request. You can't trigger this response by just navigating to the route that points to this controller and method.

You can test the `js.erb` execution by changing the respond_to block to

```rb
def my_schedule
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
  end
end
```

Then create a my_schedule.html.erb file in the same view folder as the js.erb with the following contents

```rb
<%= link_to 'Test', my_schedule_path, data: { remote: true } %>
```

Note that you may need to adjust that path, I'm just guessing on that.

Then navigate to the same path you were trying to before. You should see a link which, when clicked, will fire the js response.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean, and how this should works. I'm trying to test it, I added a link_to with remote: true in my html.erb view, some code in js.erb, but when I'm clicking on my link it throws me an error concerning my request `VM1899:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at processResponse (rails-ujs.js:272)
    at rails-ujs.js:200
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (rails-ujs.js:255)`

Comment: Maybe I'm trying to achieve something by doing it the wrong way. Here I want my user to choose something, and depending on what he chooses, I'd like to send these info to my controller and create a rails model.

Comment: Create a rails model? Or create a record in a model? Two very different things. As far as the error goes, I suspect your javascript in the `js.erb` file is wrong. Could you update your question with the javascript you're trying to execute?

Comment: A record in a model yes. My JS file just had a console.log to test it. I've figured out another way to do what I wanted. But I'm still confused about how to send a post request in ajax, to create a record in a model (for a later use)

Comment: Take a look at this article: https://medium.com/@codenode/how-to-use-remote-true-to-make-ajax-calls-in-rails-3ecbed40869b
I think you're adding an extra step where you don't need to. You could just have the form submit directly to the controller that will create the record in your model with ajax via `remote: true`

Comment: Ok I'm going to read the article, it should help to have a better grasp. Many thanks for your time !